# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Dies

Tags: php, parsing, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am screen scraping page with a bunch of subpages using Simple HTML DOM Parser. For some reason it parses the first 40 subpages just fine but when it comes to number 41 it dies with no error.

I have made [this test page](http://snuzzer.dk/pub/shdp/parse.php) and tried to log everything I do in my script aswell as some of the venets in the Simple HTML DOM Parser but I haven't been able to find the error.

Does anyone have an idea why it does when parsing URL number 41? Or does anyone know of some cases Simple HTML DOM Parser will fail?

My test page: http://snuzzer.dk/pub/shdp/parse.php

This is my script and I use a non-modified version of Simple HTML DOM Parser.
The interesting stuff happens in get_lections() and I have markede where I call Simple HTML DOM Parser.

```
define("LECTION_STATUS_REGULAR", 0);
define("LECTION_STATUS_CHANGED", 1);
define("LECTION_STATUS_CANCELLED", 2);

define("LECTION_DOCUMENTS_NONE", 0);
define("LECTION_DOCUMENTS_TRUE", 1);

define("AMOUNT_OF_WEEKS_IN_A_YEAR", 52);

include_once("simple_html_dom.php");

function clean_text($text)
{
    $text = trim($text);
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $text = utf8_decode($text);

    return $text;
}

function get_links_for_lections($weeks)
{
    echo "Finding links<br /><textarea style=\"width:70%;height:150px;\">";

    foreach($weeks as $week)
    {
        // **
        // 
        // THIS IS WHERE I CALL SIMPLE HTML DOM PARSER
        //
        // **

        echo " * Retrieving HTML...\n";
        $html = file_get_html("http://www.lectio.dk/lectio/285/SkemaNy.aspx?type=elev&elevid=2444366210&week=" . $week['week'] . $week['year']);
        echo " * HTML retrieved...\n";

        $lections_regular = $html->find('a[class="s2skemabrik s2bgbox s2withlink"]');
        $lections_changed = $html->find('a[class="s2skemabrik s2bgbox s2changed s2withlink"]');
        $lections_cancelled = $html->find('a[class="s2skemabrik s2bgbox s2cancelled s2withlink"]');
        $lections = array_merge($lections_regular, $lections_changed, $lections_cancelled);

        foreach($lections as $lection)
        {
            $links[] = "http://www.lectio.dk" . $lection->href;
        }
    }

    echo "</textarea>
    <hr />";

    return $links;
}

function get_lections($links)
{
    // Create array to hold lections
    $lections = array();

    // Loop through links
    $num = 1;
    foreach($links as $link)
    {   
        echo $num . ". " . $link . "<br />
        <textarea style=\"width:70%;height:150px;\">";

        // Initialize lection
        $lection = array();
        $lection['status'] = LECTION_STATUS_REGULAR;
        $lection['documents'] = LECTION_DOCUMENTS_NONE;

        echo " * Retrieving HTML...\n";
        $html = file_get_html($link);
        echo " * HTML retrieved\n";

        // Loop through rows
        foreach($html->find("tr") as $row)
        {
            echo " * New cell\n";

            // Get name of row
            $row_name = $row->find("th");
            $row_name = $row_name['0']->innertext;

            echo " - Row name: \"" . $row_name . "\"\n";

            if ($row_name == "Type:")
            {
                echo " - Checking type...\n";

                // Row tells what type it is
                $cell = $row->find("td");
                $content = $cell['0']->innertext;
                $lection['type'] = clean_text($content);

                echo " - Type checked\n";
            }
            else if ($row_name == "Titel:")
            {
                echo " - Checking title...\n";

                // Row tells the title
                $cell = $row->find("td");
                $content = $cell['0']->innertext;
                $lection['title'] = clean_text($content);

                echo " - Title checked\n";
            }
            else if ($row_name == "Hold:")
            {
                echo " - Checking subject...\n";

                // Row tells what the subject is
                $cell = $row->find("td");
                $content = $cell['0']->innertext;
                $lection['subject'] = clean_text($content);

                echo " - Subject checked\n";
            }
            else if ($row_name == "Lærere:")
            {
                echo " - Checking teachers...\n";

                // Row tells who the teacher is 
                $cell = $row->find("td");
                $content = $cell['0']->innertext;
                $lection['teachers'] = clean_text($content);

                echo " - Teachers checked\n";
            }
            else if ($row_name == "Lokaler:")
            {
                echo " - Checking location...\n";

                // Row tells the location
                $cell = $row->find("td");
                $content = $cell['0']->innertext;
                $lection['location'] = clean_text($content);

                echo " - Location checked\n";
            }
            else if ($row_name == "Note:")
            {
                echo " - Checking note...\n";

                // Row contains a note
                $cell = $row->find("td");
                $content = $cell['0']->innertext;
                $lection['note'] = clean_text($content);

                echo " - Note checked\n";
            }
            elseif ($row_name == "Dokumenter:")
            {
                echo " - Checking documents...\n";

                // Row contains the documents
                $cell = $row->find("td");
                $content = $cell['0']->plaintext;
                $content = clean_text($content);
                if ($content)
                {
                    // We can't get the titles of the documents as we are not logged in
                    // Instead we tell the user that there are documents available
                    $lection['documents'] = LECTION_DOCUMENTS_TRUE;
                }

                echo " - Documents checked\n";
            }
            else if ($row_name == "Lektier:")
            {
                echo " - Checking homework...\n";

                // Row contains the homework
                $cell = $row->find("td");
                $content = $cell['0']->innertext;
                $lection['homework'] = clean_text($content);

                echo " - Homework checked\n";
            }
            else if ($row_name == "Vises:")
            {
                echo " - Checking status (part 1)...\n";

                // Row tells where the lection is shown 
                $cell = $row->find("td");
                $content = $cell['0']->plaintext;
                $content = clean_text($content);
                if (strstr($content, ","))
                {
                    // If the above is true, the lection is NOT REGULAR
                    // Now we know that the lection is either changed or cancellde
                    // We assume it is changed
                    // Below we check if the lection is cancelled (Where $row_namme == "Status:")
                    $lection['status'] = LECTION_STATUS_CHANGED;
                }

                echo " - Status (part 1) checked\n";
            }
        }

        // Add lection to array of lections
        $lections[] = $lection;
        print_r($lection);

        echo " - Lection added!</textarea><br /><br />";

        $num += 1;
    }

    return $lections;
}

function get_weeks($amount_of_weeks)
{
    $weeks = array();

    // Current week
    $week_now = date('W');
    $year_now = date('Y');

    // Demo
    $week_now = 44;

    // Last week to fetch
    $last_week = $week_now + $amount_of_weeks;

    // Add weeks to array
    for ($i = $week_now; $i <= $last_week; $i++)
    {
        $week = array();

        if ($i > AMOUNT_OF_WEEKS_IN_A_YEAR)
        {
            // Week is next year
            $week['week'] = $i - AMOUNT_OF_WEEKS_IN_A_YEAR;
            $week['year'] = $year_now + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // Week is in this year
            $week['week'] = $i;
            $week['year'] = $year_now;
        }

        // Add week to weeks
        $weeks[] = $week;
    }

    return $weeks;
}

$weeks = get_weeks(5);
$links = get_links_for_lections($weeks);
$lections = get_lections($links);
echo "<hr />";
print_r($lections);
echo "<hr />";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this and it worked fine, I got up to 96. If I had to guess I'd say you reached max excution time. Try adding this at the top: `set_time_limit(0);`
Otherwise try changing your error reporting and post any errors here.

Comment: It works fine for you? That's strange. Setting `set_time_limit(0)` didn't change anything. I guess my webhotel doesn't allow me to do so. It doesn't seem like it's a timeout as it doesn't load for very long. I also find it strange that it stops exactly the same place everytime if it's a timeout.

Comment: I just tested on another server. You are right, it seems that the max execution time has been reached.