# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Long loading website

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

i am working on one project and i have a problem with one thing.
Webpage that i am going to screen scrape have a ~5-10 sec loading time because of high amount of data.

When i am trying screen scrape with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser i got no results.
Screen is blank. All elements i use is ok, because when i enter another page from the same website which has exactly the same code in the few start lines everything is working.

Is there any chance to wait for website finish loading and then screen scrape.

Thanks

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
error_reporting(0);

include_once('../../simple_html_dom.php');

function scraping_slashdot() {
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.examplepage.com/');

    // get article block
    foreach($html->find('div[id="rightBlock"]') as $article) {
        // get title1
        $item['title1'] = $article->find('div.[class="inputHead"]', 0)->plaintext;

        $ret[] = $item;
    }


    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//output
$ret = scraping_slashdot();

foreach($ret as $v) {

    echo $v['title1'];

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check other similar questions before posting a new one... ie: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7620955/1519058

Comment: I checked but nothing resolve my problem. Is it possible to add sleep(); somewhere in the code? I am trying with few combinations but can't make it to work.

Comment: Try to increase the [MAX_FILE_SIZE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17939345/1519058), if still no luck, try to use curl instead as chown in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21186309/1519058

Comment: @Rhck, did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using jquery? you can complete a function once the page has loaded by adding:

```
$(document).ready()
```

Comment: Nop. I am new at this and have no idea how to do that.
Can you give me example with code above?

Comment: after googling, i have found this tutorial which may be able to help 

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/screen-scraping-with-nodejs--net-25560

Comment: It's a php question NOT a js one !